# Bitwise operations on SINGLE BIT of std::vector<bool>. Why the error?

Tags: c++, stl, bit-manipulation, bit

I have come up with a set of rules to transform one set of bits into another.

For these to work, I basically need to xor a certain number of bits in the source set of bits (say, `result[i]=source[foo(i)]^source[bar(i)]`, where `foo` and `bar` are bounds-checked). Since I want to be able to change the size of the set, I decided to go with a `std::vector<bool>`.

Thus, I end up with:

```cpp
int foo(int i);
int bar(int i);
void baz(std::vector<bool> in, std::vector<bool>& out){
   out.clear();
   for(int i=0;i<in.size();i++){
    if(foo(i)>0 && foo(i)<in.size())
      out[i]^=in[foo(i)]
    if(bar(i)>0 && bar(i)<in.size())
      out[i]^=in[bar(i)]
   }
}
```

However, this gives me an error:

> No viable overloaded ^=

What can I do in order to be able to do this stuff?

Comment: "*xor a certain number of bits in the source set of bits*" That's not what your code is trying to do. You're trying to XOR the source with the *destination* in both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector<bool>` is messy in the best case and an abomination in the worst. Its `operator[]` does not return a `bool&` but rather a proxy object ([see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference)). This proxy does not have overloads vor all possible bitwise operations, hence you have to use ifs, its `operator=(bool)` or its `flip()`.

EDIT: I just read your code and not your description what you want to do. Setting the xor of two bits is no problem at all:

```
out[i] = in[j] ^ in[k]; // Whatever the right indices are.
```

I think what you actually want to do is along the lines of:

```cpp
bool tmp = false;
if(foo(i)>0 && foo(i)<in.size())
 tmp^=in[foo(i)];
if(bar(i)>0 && bar(i)<in.size())
 out[i]=tmp^in[bar(i)];
```

That is, if you want to return `in[bar(i)]^in[foo(i)]` if both pass the bounds check, return `in[j]` if only one (here denoted by `j`) passes the bounds check and `false` if none of them pass it.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is a special container.  It's like a `std::vector<int>`, but the standard allows for `std::vector<bool>` to pack its elements into single bits which means it returns a [proxy object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference) when you use `operator[]`.  That object doesn't have an overload for `operator ^=` so you can't use it.  What you can do is write out the long form of `^=` like

```
out[i] = out[i] ^ in[foo(i)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<bool>::operator[]` returns a proxy class. You can see the documentation on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference).

You can use `static_cast<bool>` so get an actual bool value and use that in your XOR.

```
out[i] = static_cast<bool>(out[i]) ^ in[foo(i)];
```

**Edit:** Or as pointed out by Max, simply rewriting it will do an implicit conversion so the cast is redundant.

```
out[i] = out[i] ^ in[foo(i)];
```

Comment: `static_cast` by itself won't fix anything. You can't use the result of the `static_cast` on the left hand side of `^=` either, which is what the error stems from.

Comment: Good point, just rewriting it will do an implicit conversion.